# how does the cpu knows that the data in memory is data or a command? (C programming)

Tags: c, memory

I expect that that data begins at for example 0x100 (memory location) and everything before that it's commands... But I am really not sure! Thanks for help!

okay, to detail my question: I see the memory as a long array with one byte space. The space is filled with hex numbers. But the variables can fill the memory from for example 0x0000 - 0xffff. But how do you know that for example 0x002f is a command (for example 'mov') or just a number as data?

Comment: It is simpler than what you expect. If the processor is executing it, it is code. If it is reading it into a register, it is data. That is all.

Comment: The point is the cpu doesn't know if it's data or instructions. I suppose you mean "instruction" when you write "command". Do you have a specific CPU in mind ? Reformulate your question. It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: It's all mixed up and depends on the interpretation you make, and that's the power of it! If there was a pre-determined location for code only and data only, you couldn't build compilers because the data they work on is also code ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CPU doesn't know. It's all about conventions.

When you start your computer or embedded device it starts executing a bootloaer from a flash storage.

In turn, the bootloader loads startup code from persistent storage to memory and starts executing (typically the OS kernel) at the address where it loaded it.

In turn, the kernel will load additional modules and init code at known memory locations and execute from there.

At some point, memory virtualization is enabled, and executable files are loaded in memory and each is associated with a process and its address space. The executable header and OS conventions define code and data segments locations.

But the code segment may contain embedded data, and dynamically allocated memory may contain code, for instance in just-in-time compilers or malicious programs.

Ok to illustrate: imagine the address space of a running compiler...

```
[ code seg from .exe ] [ data seg from .exe ] [ dynamic alloc ]
```

The only difference between these memory regions is that [code] is Read+Execut, [data] is ReadOnly, [dynamic] is Read+Write, sometimes +Execute

- [code] contains

  - mainly machine instructions
  - but it may contain immediate data, such as integer constants and so on
- [data] contains

  - things like strings for your language keywords, error messages, etc.
  - code because you have a dictionary of machine instructions so that you can generate code
- [dynamic] contains

  - runtime allocated data structures such as strings, trees, etc.
  - runtime generated code, which will be written to the exe the compiler is building
  - runtime generated code, which will be executed by a jit for computing complex expressions at compile-time

So you see, you can have data and code in any section. That's what makes computers powerful, see also the [turing machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine).

Comment: so actually the data section thinks they have all the adress space for themselves, and so the code section do? the virtual memory takes care of it?

Comment: @int80: no, the process thinks it has the whole address space, and puts its data and code segments at sufficiently distant address blocks in this virtual memory. The OS maps this to real memory.

Comment: ok, but isnt a convention which says e.g. 0x4B = mov (command) ? and if it is how does the if you like the kernel knows that (i mean that this is command not a data) since the cpu doesn care. I thought the control unit of the cpu cares...

Comment: @int80: 0x4B is a byte, it could be part of a machine-code stream which at certain locations could be interpreted as `mov`, but it could also be a pixel in an image, part of a web page, or of a floating point constant...

Comment: first thanks what you're saying makes really sense. So the kernel does the work to interpret the byte as what the programmer wants it to be?

Comment: for the data/code distinction, it's the processor that interprets it: if you `load` it's data, it you `jmp` or `call` it's code. The OS gives some sense to all that by doing the right loads followed by the right jumps. It also flags some memory pages as non executable, so that you can never jump into it, forcing them to be interpreted as data.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the CPU doesn't know. It just execute instructions. However the *operating system* with the help or the *memory management* unit may flag some memory page as executable or not, preventing the cpu for executing it.

Answer (score 1):

> How does the cpu knows that the data in memory is data or a command?

It only knows from the context - you can (leaving aside execution protection of modern CPUs) very well set your instruction pointer to a block of data and let the CPU execute it (most likely with useless results). The same is true for the other way round: when an instruction is accessing a memory location, it is taken as data to work with - but it could even be part of your code memory (reading the opcodes of CPU instructions).

So in essence, there is no distinction between data and code memory, at least not on CPUs which are built according to the [von-Neumann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture) architecture.

On the other hand, there are also CPUs (e.g. the PIC microcontroller series) which are built according to the [Harvard architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture) - on these systems, it is not possible to treat data as code or code as data since the access paths are physically separated.

> I expect that that data begins at for example 0x100

That depends on the CPU and the operating system. You probably refer to ancient `.COM` files from MS-DOS (where *code* began at 0x100) or to some other architecture. On modern operating systems, there is usually a virtual memory management involved.

Comment: so its all mixed up? my question for example 0x11 is a command but the programmer means that as data... ehhh there must be a rule which says this is data or this is commands? probably like in assembler where you divide it in sections... but they still in the same memory adress space?

Comment: From a CPU perspective, it can be both, data or command (instruction). If it is a valid opcode, it can be executed by the CPU, and it can also be loaded into a register to execute operations on it. If you are referring to `C`, it is the compiler (and linker) which generates CPU instruction from your code and puts the data into appropriate sections so that the execution environment (operating system) knows where the executable code and where the data is located

Comment: so are the commands using the same adress space like the data or different?

Comment: i mean the virtual address space